# WPF textblock binding in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, textblock

I'm updating some existing WPF code and my application has a number of textblocks defined like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlockPropertyA"><Run Text="{Binding PropertyA}"/></TextBlock>
```

In this case, "PropertyA" is a property of my business class object defined like this:

```
public class MyBusinessObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    private string _propertyA;
    public string PropertyA
    {
        get { return _propertyA; }
        set
        {
            if (_propertyA == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _propertyA = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PropertyA"));
        }
    }

    // my business object also contains another object like this
    public SomeOtherObject ObjectA = new SomeOtherObject();

    public MyBusinessObject()
    {
        // constructor
    }
}
```

Now I have a TextBlock that I need to bind to one of the properties of ObjectA which, as you can see, is an object in MyBusinessObject.  In code, I'd refer to this as:

```
MyBusinessObject.ObjectA.PropertyNameHere
```

Unlike my other bindings, "PropertyNameHere" isn't a direct property of MyBusinessObject but rather a property on ObjectA.  I'm not sure how to reference this in a XAML textblock binding. Can anyone tell me how I'd do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before `<Run Text="{Binding ObjectA.PropertyNameHere}" />` will work you have to make `ObjectA` itself a property because binding will only work with properties not fields.

```
// my business object also contains another object like this
public SomeOtherObject ObjectA { get; set; }

public MyBusinessObject()
{
    // constructor
    ObjectA = new SomeOtherObject();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply type this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjectA.PropertyNameHere"/>
```

You may want to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` within your `ObjectA` class, as changing properties of the class will not be picked up by the `PropertyChanged` methods in your `MyBusinessObject` class.

Answer (score 3):

Try to instantiate ObjectA in the same way as you are doing for PropertyA (Ie. as a property, with a public getter / setter, and calling OnPropertyChanged), then your XAML can be :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjectA.PropertyNameHere}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a same as you do for `PropertyA` like follows,

```
OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ObjectA"));
```

on Designer XAML,

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ObjectAProperty" Text="{Binding ObjectA.PropertyNameHere}" />
```

Comment: Yes i know that, in propery, he didn't call Property changed event... so included that first and added the xaml

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In code:

```
public MyBusinessObject Instance { get; set; }

Instance = new MyBusinessObject();
```

In XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Instance.PropertyNameHere" />
```